# Implicit connection of Action Methods with Views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am currently working in a brownfield **ASP.NET MVC 3** project in **VS2010**.

In this project, views and controllers are in separate projects. This is not something that I have seen before. In each action method there is no explicit stating of view name as below.

```
return View("viewName",passingModel);//projects where controllers and views are in same
```

I have done this implicitly in VS2012 by right clicking on the view and do `add view`. So I was not bothered about where is this connection between action method's return view and the view is stated.

**Unlike in VS2012**, in VS2010 I can not navigate to the view that is related to one particular action method by right clicking on View and doing `go to view`.

I tried to understand this by doing this small experiment. I created a `Controller` and created a `Action Method` call `xxxx` and I created a view for that implicitly as mentioned above and searched the word `xxxx` in entire solution but this word only appeared in controller and in the view.

So, I was unsuccessful in finding the answer. I think visual studio itself creating its own mapping to achieve this. 
I would like to know who these implicit connections are created among action methods and views to understand what is going on in my project.

Edit:

Both the projects which contains controllers and views are class libraries. not asp.net mvc projects.

`Global.aspx` file contains this:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            DependenciesHelper.Register(new HttpContextWrapper(Context));

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RoutingHelper.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void Application_End()
        {
            //Should close the index
            //If this method is not executed, the search engine will still work.
            SearchService.CloseIndex();
        }
```

Comment: My understanding is that by convention if you call `View` with no view name it'll look for a view with the same name as the action.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Do you have any idea of how the connection happen when controllers and views are in separate projects?

Comment: Think your conversation with Liverpool covers this but basically it happens in the exact same way. The MVC code will use reflection to find relevant methods/classes and the configured routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping is fairly straightforward. For example if you have a controller called "MyBrilliantController" and an action method called "MyExcellentAction" which returned just `return View();` it would map to (in the UI project) `~/Views/MyBrilliant/MyExcellentAction.cshtml`

The only time where this is different is when you are working with "Areas" - but the mapping is effectively the same, it would just consider the area folder first (ie `~/Areas/MyArea/Views/MyBrilliant/MyExcellentAction.cshtml`)

Hope that helps.

**EDIT - You can also specify namespaces in the global.asax file on each route for the engine to find controllers**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }, // Parameter defaults
        new string[] {
            // namespaces in which to find controllers for this route
            "MySolution.MyControllersLib1.Helpers", 
            "MySolution.MyControllersLib2.Helpers",
            "MySolution.MyControllersLib3.Helpers" 
        } 
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what would happen if controllers are in separate project. As I have stated in edit, they are both class libraries.

Comment: It would map in exactly the same way. It's slightly dependant on your routing, and area registration (if you're using Areas) but you could have 1000 controllers in 1000 separate dlls and it would still map in the default way until you tell it otherwise.

Comment: I am not familiar with Areas, in the project controllers are separately in a folder(folder is not named as `Controllers`, its called `Helpers`). Views are in another project, but they are organized under Views folder and Controller name Folder and then views. Is this automatically detected by the folder structure or have to specify in `Global.aspx`. Sorry I still could not grasp the idea, :(

Comment: Forgetting Areas, it doesn't matter **where** the controller classes area - in the "default" way ASP.NET MVC works, they just have to have the word "Controller" at the end of the file name (ie `XxxxxController`), and inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. You can also specify the namespaces for the engine to look for controllers in the routing - I'll add an example above.

Comment: I understand now. Controllers are identified like this, Then how does the Views are identified. Is it just using the folder structure? `Views->Controller->view.cshtml`

Comment: Yup. Or you can do it explicitly, but that's not what you're asking.